# ERROR TypeError: data.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular

```
ERROR TypeError: data.slice is not a function
#atMatTableDataSource.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/table.es5.js.MatTableDataSource._orderData (table.es5.js:742)

#at MapSubscriber.project (table.es5.js:675)
#atMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
#atMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
```

I am consuming a JSON response and attempting to display it in the UI through angular material mat-table. please find the attached snippet of code and let me know what is the mistake in the code which I have made or do I need to change my approach to achieve this

## JSON webservice

```
{
"data": [
{
  "action": "Ok",
  "created_user": "slstst5",
  "latest_instance": 7713997,
  "modified_dt": "Thu, 12 Jul 2018 06:27:32 GMT",
  "no_of_btl": 159,
  "request": 238244193,
  "sales_rep": "slstst5",
  "status_cd": "Submitted to Prov."
},
```

## Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {sot} from './sot.model';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SotServiceService {
private serviceUrl ="service URL";

constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }
getuser():Observable<sot[]>{
  return this.http.get<sot[]>(this.serviceUrl);
}
}
```

## table.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import {MatSort, MatSortable, MatTableDataSource,PageEvent, MatPaginator} 
from '@angular/material';
import {SotServiceService} from '../sot-service.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-sot-table',
templateUrl: './sot-table.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./sot-table.component.css']
})
export class SotTableComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator : MatPaginator;
dataSource;
//displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'username', 'email', 'phone', 'website'];
displayedColumns = ['request', 'status_cd', 'sales_rep', 'created_user', 
'modified_dt', 'action','no_of_btl'];
//displayedColumns=['userId','id','title','body']
constructor(private sotservice :SotServiceService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.sotservice.getuser().subscribe(result => {

  if(!result){
    return ;
  }
  this.dataSource= new MatTableDataSource(result);
  this.dataSource.sort= this.sort;
  this.dataSource.paginator=this.paginator;
 })
 }

}
```

Error snapshot:
[image: Error Snapshot]

Comment: This is not valid JSON

Comment: True as mentioned above, but that could be because you just got a snippet of your JSON (?) But the issue is also that your array is inside `data` property of your JSON, so I guess you just want the array...

Comment: Yeah you are right I have attached a snippet of my JSON. Yes my array is inside the data property of JSON, I am trying to retrieve the values from the data Array and display it in the table

Comment: {
  "data": [
    {
      "action": "Ok",
      "created_user": "ab28974",
      "latest_instance": 7720104,
      "modified_dt": "Fri, 13 Jul 2018 08:05:26 GMT",
      "no_of_btl": 20,
      "request": 238219884,
      "sales_rep": "ab28974",
      "status_cd": "Keying In Progress"
    } ]}

Comment: How would you do this, if you have multiple Objects inside of your Object?

Answer (score 18):

This happens sometimes when you are using the slice function on wrong data type. Slice works on an array, not an object. It might happen that you are trying to slice an object.

Answer (score 9):

Your `data` object is inside of the `result` object. You will need to do the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sotservice.getuser()
    .subscribe(result => {
      if(!result){
        return;
      }

      this.dataSource= new MatTableDataSource(result.data);
      this.dataSource.sort= this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator=this.paginator;
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried the (result.data) however I am getting the error "Property 'data' does not exist on type 'sot[]'."

Comment: Your json and your model aren't matching then

Comment: How would you do this if you had multiple Objects inside of your Object? @WesleyCoetzee

Comment: @BlueScoreMan What do you mean? Maybe post a new question on SO and tag me, include the json etc.

Answer (score 5):

Happens because of you are trying to slice an object. Slice works on an array, not an object.

Answer (score 3):

This error is due to the array returned by your webservice. 
result contains the array of data. To avoid data.slice is not a function error, you will need to point your result to result.data as mentioned by Wesley Coetzee.
You can safely remove observable from the service as well. If you are not sure about the Sot object, replace it with any or remove it

P.S.
This error also occurs if you have sub-array in result.data as well. In that case you will do something like, 
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res.data.yourSubArray);

Answer (score 2):

You Should use

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result.data);
```

Because there is a key named as 'data' in your json file which contain array of your data object.

Answer (score 2):

My observable stream returns data from local indexedDB storage (no backend), and my mistake was not checking array length of the stream parameter before assigning it to MatTableDataSource, which resulted in the same type error. Here is my fix:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.dataStream = this.storageService.getDataStream().subscribe((activeDataList: any) => { 
      if (activeDataList.length) { 
         this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(activeDataList);
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try change this line `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);` to    `this.datasource.result = results['Data']` then have your dataSource initialized just outside of your constructor like `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();`

What you'll basically doing here is to tell your code that there is an element named Data in my result so give me the value or data of this element and assign it to my data-source, hope it helps, had the similar issue and this is how I resolved it

Answer (score 0):

just make sure data is an array / list of your expected data for the table, otherwise won't be possible to slice.

simple