# How to fix 'ERROR TypeError: data.slice is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I am trying to display JSON from my backend on my Angular dashboard with angular material mat-table.

I have done this successfully a lot in the past where my JSON response was a string or a list, but I struggle here with a dictionary.

I have tried to follow the advice [shown on Question 51304884](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304884/error-typeerror-data-slice-is-not-a-function), with no luck.

I found a solution that works, i.e. putting my dict into a list in the backend, but I would like to understand how to do it with a dict.

The code for my dashboard looks like this:

## component.ts

```
export class RunningContainersComponent {

  containers = new MatTableDataSource<Containers>();
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['serverName', 'containerCount'];

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private cadenzaService: CadenzaService) {
  }

  onUploadResponse(response) {
    this.containers.data = response;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.containers.sort = this.sort;
    this.cadenzaService.getRunningContainers().subscribe(response => this.onUploadResponse(response));
  }
}
```

## service.ts

```
  getRunningContainers(): Observable<Containers[]> {
    const url = backendUrl + `/running-containers`;
    return this.http.get<Containers[]>(url, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set(
        'Authorization', `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`)
    })
      .pipe(
        tap(response => CadenzaService.log(`${response.length} containers received`)),
        catchError(this.handleError('getRunningContainers', []))
      );
  }
```

## component.html

```
<div class="global">
  <div class="dashboard-status mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="containers" matSort matSortActive="serverName" matSortDirection="asc">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="serverName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Engine name</th>
        <td mat-cell style="width:150px;" *matCellDef="let row">{{row.serverName}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="containerCount">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Running containers</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.containerCount}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

## The error I get

```
core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: data.slice is not a function
    at MatTableDataSource.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/table.es5.js.MatTableDataSource._orderData (table.es5.js:706)
    at MapSubscriber.project (table.es5.js:639)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/observable/combineLatest.js.CombineLatestSubscriber.notifyNext (combineLatest.js:83)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:15)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/observable/combineLatest.js.CombineLatestSubscriber.notifyNext (combineLatest.js:83)
```

## What I would like to see

I have two keys (name of the server and number of Docker containers running on each server) that I would like to display in a table. One column showing the name, the other the number.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this should be:`this.containers= response;` not `this.containers.data = response;`

Comment: I tried and I got this error: "Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource".

Comment: How about, `this.containers = new MatTableDataSource(response);`

Comment: @Remi `console.log(response)`?

Comment: @GopeshSharma: I no longer have any error in the console, but my table is still empty. And I know "reponse" is not empty and it is what I want since I verified using console.log.

Comment: @Remi Can you show your response object?

Comment: My response is something like this:

Object
Engine-2: {containerCount: 3}
Engine-4: {containerCount: 3}
__proto__: Object

What I get from the backend is this:

{"Engine-2":{"containerCount":3},"Engine-4":{"containerCount":3}}

Comment: I found a cleaner solution in the backend, giving me a nice list to show in the table. So I no longer have any issue.

Answer (score -3):

this is how you do it

```
let str = 'hi how are you';
let array = [];
array = str.split(' ').map(function (word) {
                   return word
                })
```

Comment: Are you serious?